Airflow dag, wait for certain period if triggered at a certain time
I have an airflow DAG dag-A that is triggered from another DAG, sometimes, this dag-A is triggered at 4 pm UTC (midnight EST), and when it gets triggered at midnight EST (4PM UTC), I want it to wait for 30 minutes and then start running at 16:30 UTC.
Generally it should run when it is triggered, but if triggered between 16:00 and 16:30 UTC it should wait till 16:30.
I have done this using sleep method, but trying to do same using TimeSensor, as that would be non blocking while sleep is blocking.
Here is my code that is leading me into infinite loop, as it keep waiting for 16:30 even if task was check_time returns false. I want that if it is not between 16:00 and 16:30 then run the dq_taks but if it is between 16:00 and 16:30 then wait until it becomes 16:30 and then run dq_task.
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.time import TimeSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime

def check_time_and_delay():
    now = datetime.now()
    return now.hour == 16 and now.minute >= 0 and now.minute <= 30

with DAG(
    'delayed_dag',
    default_args={'start_date': days_ago(1)},
    schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:

    check_time = PythonOperator(
        task_id='check_time',
        python_callable=check_time_and_delay
    )

    wait_until_12_30 = TimeSensor(
        task_id='wait_until_12_30',
        target_time=atetime.strptime('16:30:00', '%H:%M:%S').time(),
        mode='reschedule',
        timeout=1800 
    )

    run_dq_check = PythonOperator(
        task_id='run_dq_check',
        python_callable=lambda: print("Running DQ check")
    )

    # Define the task flow
    check_time >> [wait_until_12_30, run_dq_check]
    wait_until_12_30 >> run_dq_check


The code that works but uses sleep method:
def check_if_midnight_and_wait(execution_date):
    if execution_date.hour == 4 and execution_date.minute < 30:   # 4PM utc is midnight in EST
        wait_time = timedelta(minutes=30 - execution_date.minute)
        print(f"Waiting for {wait_time} minutes to start at 00:30 AM EST.")
        sleep(wait_time.total_seconds())
# task:
  wait_and_start = PythonOperator(
        task_id='wait_and_start',
        python_callable=check_if_midnight_and_wait,
        provide_context=True
    )

 wait_and_start >> dq_check


Try to use BranchPythonOperator
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.time_sensor import TimeSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime, time

def check_time_and_branch():
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    if now.hour == 16 and 0 <= now.minute < 30:
        return 'wait_until_16_30'
    return 'run_dq_check'

with DAG(
    'delayed_dag',
    default_args={'start_date': days_ago(1)},
    schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:

    check_time = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='check_time',
        python_callable=check_time_and_branch
    )

    wait_until_16_30 = TimeSensor(
        task_id='wait_until_16_30',
        target_time=time(16, 30),
        mode='reschedule',
        timeout=1800 
    )

    run_dq_check = PythonOperator(
        task_id='run_dq_check',
        python_callable=lambda: print("Running DQ check")
    )

    check_time >> [wait_until_16_30, run_dq_check]
    wait_until_16_30 >> run_dq_check


The problem is wait_untill taks still keep on waiting after time 16:30 is passed. The wait_untill_16_30 task never completes, it just times out.
